# What does the $ behind var$ mean?

Tags: typescript, variables, angular7, ngrx, var

I'm learning angular7, ngrx and typescript.
What does the $ behind var$ mean?

```
export class JokeListPage {

jokes$: Observable<Joke[]>;

constructor( public store: Store<JokeState> ){
    this.jokes$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectJokes));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is used to indicate that the variable is an Observable. The $ naming paradigm originated with Andre Saltz and suggests pluralizing all variable names that contain observables or streams. It is considered as a good coding practice. Also please refer -> https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables

Comment: Ah I see, so it's just ngrx naming convention? cool... thanks man

Comment: Exactly.. no problem. Even I picked up ngrx pretty recently. It is small but really tricky. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does the $ behind var$ mean?

Its a naming convention for observables. If `foo` represents one item, `foos` would represent multiple `foo` items in English (pluralization). Using `$` instead of `s` makes it easier to spot, hence `foo$` (read foos)